# Haptic feedback during animation - mimic UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, animation, haptic-feedback

I created the circle with deck of cards, that user can spin to select one. After the paning ends, it snaps to designated angle with a nice deceleration animation. In future there will some kind of indication that the card at 45 degrees is the selected one.
I would like to indication that the selection changed with haptic feedback, just like in `UIPickerView`. For now I am trying to add haptic feedback to the deceleration animation. My idea was to make feedback generator and call `.selectionChanged()` in animation as many times as number of cards that were skipped. But for now I decided to just simply call it 3 times. Unfortunately, none of my ideas work - even creating a separate `UIViewPropertyAnimator` does not work. I suppose I should only put animatable properties in animation closure. The animator itself works right - the deceleration animation works.

```
        animator.addAnimations {
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 0.0, animations: {
                    self.selectionGenerator.selectionChanged()
                })
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 0.0, animations: {
                    self.selectionGenerator.selectionChanged()
                })
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 0.0, animations: {
                    self.selectionGenerator.selectionChanged()
                })
            })
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
```

[image: screen shoot]

How can I mimic the haptic feedback behaviour of for example DatePicker , which vibrates when selection changes?

Answer (score 0):

you can add haptic feedback using 
 **HAPTICA**  https://github.com/efremidze/Haptica
and add this feedback in animation loop i hope it will work... :)

Comment: Haptica does't use anything different than I just did. It's just a nice wrapper around the same API I use. Why would it work differently?